# Spring data. Override generic interface method

Tags: java, spring, generics, java-8, spring-data

I've checked how to override generics. Considering `CrudRepository` I can override:

```
<S extends T> S save(S var1);
```

in my repository with:

```
public interface ChannelDetailsRepository extends IgniteRepository<ChannelDetails, Long> {
  @Override
  default ChannelDetails save(ChannelDetails entity) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
...
}
```

but some cases is not clear yet:

```
<S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> var1);
```

i've tried use (in same `ChannelDetailsRepository` interface)

```
@Override
default Iterable<ChannelDetails> save(Iterable<ChannelDetails> entities) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

my try failed with compilation errors:

```
Error:(28, 38) java: name clash: save(java.lang.Iterable<com.nextiva.calendar.entity.ChannelDetails>) in com.nextiva.calendar.dao.ignite.ChannelDetailsRepository and <S>save(java.lang.Iterable<S>) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
Error:(26, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

and I have no ideas how to fix this generic overriding.

Comment: In short: `<S extends T> S save(S var1)` means that your method is supposed to work for _any_ `S` that extends `T`, not for some particular `S` that extends `T`.  You'll need to move `S` to be a type parameter of the class, not the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep the additional type parameter `S` so the method accepts and returns subtypes of `T` respectively `ChannelDetails`.

```
@Override
default <S extends ChannelDetails> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Comment: @CinCout What do you consider to be the question that is not answered? I took "I have no ideas how to fix this generic overriding." to be the question, i.e. "How do I fix the error and make my method override the one in the interface?"

Comment: @CinCout better?